# What is the meaning of the number 27 in Fives’ CT number?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, clones

CT-27-5555 -- AKA “Fives” -- has the numbers 27 and 5555 in his CT number, unlike Rex, Cody, Gree, and the rest of Domino Squadron (barring Droidbait). Droidbait’s CT number is CT-00-2010 and Fox’s is CT-0000/1010. As far as I can tell, there are no other clones with the number 27 in their CT number.

*What is the purpose of the bonus set of numbers in the clones’ CT numbers?*

Legends or canon is fine.

Comment: Purely guesswork, but perhaps it's the "generation" number?  If the numbers are just serial numbers, and limited to 4 digits, you'd only have 9,999 clones (10,000 if you allow for zero) before you needed a new designation.  Even at 27-9999, you'd only have unique IDs for a little over a quarter of a million clones.  For a Grand Army of the Republic of millions of clones, even the two-digit "bonus" number seems inadequate to produce unique IDs.  But definitely, 4 digits would not have sufficed.

Comment: It might be a Clone Cadet designation. Echo was CT-21-0408 when he was a cadet in Domino Squad, but Bad Batch has his number as CT-1409. Fives was CT-27-5555 when he was with Echo in Domino but also went by CT-5555 and then ARC-5555. Bravo Squad had CT-66-#### designations, except for CT-27-3555. @CaptAlgorithm could be correct and it's a generational number but there were over a million clones ready at the onset of the war and the ##-#### designations wouldn't be sufficient with the millions more being grown (and the 5 million ordered during the war), even with CC-, RC-, and ARC-.